# MiniProfiler, EntityFramework code first and background tasks nullreference

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, mvc-mini-profiler

I use EF 4.2 code first in my mvc3 project.

miniprofiler works fine (sql + mvc), but I've got an issue with async tasks.

I perform 'em this way (*is this method ok? I feel a bit uneasy with this `new DatabaseContext()`*)

```
public static void PerformAsycAction(this User user, Action<User> action)
{
   ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(_ =>
   {
     var context = new DatabaseContext();
     MiniProfilerEF.Initialize();
     var consistantUser = context.Set<User>().Get(user.Id);
     action(consistantUser);
     context.SaveChanges();
   });
}
```

I've got proper line in Application_Start:

```
  protected void Application_Start()
    {
        MiniProfilerEF.Initialize();
        ...
    }
```

The excpetion is thrown during the first operation with db in `action(consistantUser);`
here is the trace:

> at MvcMiniProfiler.MiniProfiler.AddSqlTiming(SqlTiming stats) in C:\Users\sam\Desktop\mvc-mini-profiler\MvcMiniProfiler\MiniProfiler.cs:line 274
>       at MvcMiniProfiler.SqlTiming..ctor(DbCommand command, ExecuteType type, MiniProfiler profiler) in C:\Users\sam\Desktop\mvc-mini-profiler\MvcMiniProfiler\SqlTiming.cs:line 137
>       at MvcMiniProfiler.SqlProfiler.ExecuteStartImpl(DbCommand command, ExecuteType type) in C:\Users\sam\Desktop\mvc-mini-profiler\MvcMiniProfiler\SqlProfiler.cs:line 39
>       at MvcMiniProfiler.SqlProfilerExtensions.ExecuteStart(SqlProfiler sqlProfiler, DbCommand command, ExecuteType type) in C:\Users\sam\Desktop\mvc-mini-profiler\MvcMiniProfiler\SqlProfiler.cs:line 93
>       at MvcMiniProfiler.MiniProfiler.MvcMiniProfiler.Data.IDbProfiler.ExecuteStart(DbCommand profiledDbCommand, ExecuteType executeType) in C:\Users\sam\Desktop\mvc-mini-profiler\MvcMiniProfiler\MiniProfiler.IDbProfiler.cs:line 14
>       at MvcMiniProfiler.Data.ProfiledDbCommand.ExecuteDbDataReader(CommandBehavior behavior) in C:\Users\sam\Desktop\mvc-mini-profiler\MvcMiniProfiler\Data\ProfiledDbCommand.cs:line 158
>       at System.Data.Common.DbCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior behavior)
>       at System.Data.EntityClient.EntityCommandDefinition.ExecuteStoreCommands(EntityCommand entityCommand, CommandBehavior behavior)

what am I doing wrong?
Any help will be appreciated.

**EDIT:** I tried to initialize MiniProfiler (`MiniProfilerEF.Initialize();`) again, in the thread where backgroung task is performd (before initiating DatabaseContext), and there is another exception now:

> Unable to cast object of type 'MvcMiniProfiler.Data.EFProfiledDbConnection' to type 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection

In fact, it's not neccessary to profile the queries in the background thread, but it **crashes** the whole thread, so the application doesn't work properly, and I have to disavble the whole profiler. Is there a way to disable it for that, background, thread to prevent it from crashing?

Comment: What is the actual exception?

Comment: Have you validated that you aren't passing null in to any of those functions?

Comment: sure. Same exact code works without profiler (without call in ApplicationStart).

Comment: @BryanCrosby, what do you mean by 'those functions'? I use MiniProfiler by SO team, and I do not pass anything to functions in MvcMiniProfiler namespace as I don't call 'em explicitly.

Comment: Just a note about your `DatabaseContext`: you'd better wrap it into `using`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code breaks when it tries to access your connection string because the connection string is an Entity Framework style connection string.

When passing connection string to the mini-profiler you have to extract the actual connection string from the EF connection string.

```
EntityConnection connection = 
    new EntityConnection(ConfigurationManager
                   .ConnectionStrings["ConnectionStringName"].ConnectionString));

string connectionString = connection.StoreConnection.ConnectionString;
```